# How can I quote the data within my cells?

Tags: excel

I have 2 cells that contain data that I need to wrap inside quotes like so:

"cell data 1"[tab]"cell data 2"

When I try and save the file from within excel, only some of the rows are quoted. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

double quotes doesn't help?

```
" asfm ""embedded"" data "
```

Comment: Hi John,

Thanks but I have 13K rows. What I want to do is import all of this data into a database and am trying to use Excel to massage the data. I have the columns seperated but the data just isn't going in. I just pulled a single row of data from my file and manually put quotes around the data and it still isn't going into the db. Would you happen to have any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Jim. What DB are you talking about? John's answer is fully correct due to your question above.
Putting double quotes inside the quoted area lets Excel printing out one quoting char.
="""" results in printing out "

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a text editor (like TextPad or Notepad++) for this kind of job. Find replace is more powerful in these editors.

If your data is tab separated, you can easily copy paste data between Excel and Textpad/Notepad++ without losing any formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Could you detail "some of the rows"?

Do you escape your other string for quotes ? This is usually the issue when exporting data as text. You have some unwanted chars that broke your cells' value.

Still would like to know a little bit more.

cu

Answer (score 0):

I'm also unclear as to what the required format is, but you could use the Char(9) function to get the ascii tab character.

Assuming your two cells are in columns a and b, if you use the formula

```
=A2&""""&CHAR(9)&""""&B2
```

and you save as CSV, you will see the result.

```
cell data 1,cell data 2,"cell data 1""  ""cell data 2"
```

You can then do a search and replace on "" to change it to " if that's what you need.